# How to get line number for general ASTNode in the source code?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

How can I implement this method in the basic
class ASTNode so that I can obtain different ASTNode line number easier? 
For exampel, if I want to get MethodDeclaration location I need to write code

```
@Override
public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
    int lineNum = ((CompilationUnit) node.getRoot()).getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition());
    return super.visit(node);
}
```

However, I want to get location information like this

```
@Override
public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
    int lineNum = node.getLineNumber();
    return super.visit(node);
}
```

`CompilationUnit` provides a method called `getLineNumber` implemented with `lineEndTable` and general `ASTNode` only have a field named `startPosition`, so is it possible that I can obtain a `lineEntTable` in the abstract class `ASTNode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible...?" No, individual nodes like `MethodDeclaration` don't have this information. In order to avoid redundancy `lineEndTable` is stored in only one particular node, the `CompilationUnit`. Given you have already found a solution there is no benefit in looking for another solution. The API is sufficient and the extra code you have to write is minimal.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I have a project that finish some grammer checkers using `jdt` so I need to get the 
mapping relations between `CompilationUnit` and java source file. Can u comment my extra code I write for getting the mapping relations?

Comment: And I really want to know how to copy the` lineEndTable` in `ASTNode` level.@Stephan Herrmann

Comment: `lineEndTable` is private in `CompilationUnit` and thus not intended for external use. Since JDT is open source you can of course modify the sources to your liking - but in that case we assume you know what you are doing. Moreover, I don't see why you are struggling so hard just to save one line of code in your visit method.

Answer (score 0):

I find a compromise method to do it. I add two methods for abstract class ASTNode.

```
public int getStartingLineNumber() {
    if (this.getRoot().getNodeType() == 15) {
        return (((CompilationUnit)this.getRoot()).getLineNumber(this.getStartPosition()));
    }
    if (this instanceof Comment) {
        ASTNode alter = ((Comment) this).getAlternateRoot();
        if (alter.getNodeType() == 15) {
            return (((CompilationUnit) alter).getLineNumber(this.getStartPosition()));
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public String fileName;

public String getFileName() {
    if (this.getRoot().getNodeType() == 15) {
        return ((CompilationUnit) this.getRoot()).getFileName();
    }
    if (this instanceof Comment) {
        ASTNode alter = ((Comment) this).getAlternateRoot();
        if (alter.getNodeType() == 15) {
            return ((CompilationUnit) alter).getFileName();
        }
    }
    return fileName;
}`
```

And I also add a `setFileName` method for CompilationUnit so that I can get `fileName` and `LineNum` info for each ASTNode.

```
CompilationUnit result = (CompilationUnit)(astParser.createAST(null));
result.setFileName(javaFilePath);
```

Can anyone give me a better solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
int startLine = ((CompilationUnit) node.getRoot()).getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition());
int endLine = ((CompilationUnit) node.getRoot()).getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()+node.getLength());
```